# Where to handle request that deal with multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Example: a `Survey` has many `Question`s. A request is made to create a survey, and the request contains the survey title and metadata, plus all the questions.

This all happens on one page -- when the user clicks submit, the survey and its questions are created.

So far I have all the logic in the `SurveysController` but I'm not sure if this is MVC, especially because I have methods like `add_question` and `remove_question`.

Is there a preferred way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're creating the questions through [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), then it would be okay.

--

When you mention `add_question` / `remove question` - *this* would be best handled in a separate `questions` controller (with [nested resource routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :surveys do
   resources :questions, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

This allows you to use the following:

```
#app/controllers/surverys_controller.rb
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
    def show
       @survey = Survey.find params[:id]
       @new_question = @survey.questions.new
    end
end

#app/views/surveys/show.html.erb
<%= @survey.title %>
<% @survey.questions.each do |question| %>
   <%= link_to "Remove", surveys_question_path(@survey, question), method: :delete %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for @question do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :text %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This would keep your controllers conventional.

Comment: Looked into `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, this seems to be what I was after.

Answer (score -1):

Nested resources:

```
resources :surveys do
  resources :questions # check http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes for generated routes
end
```

Now you can create QuestionsController with normal CRUD actions and survey_id in params. I.e:

```
class QuestionsController
  def create
    @question = Question.new(survey_id: params[:survey_id], ... )
  end
end
```

And to create survey with all questions at once use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on Survey model http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html